# Xpages tabbed pane

Tags: maps, xpages, pane

We are trying to add a Google map custom control to the 4th tab of a tabbed pane in XPages

When we do we get this:

A map with ONLY the first small 10th of the map draw in the top left corner.

As you can see only the first section of the map will load.

I've googled around and it appears that if the map IS NOT on the first tab it wont work without a 'tab change recall of the map initialise function'

I've tested this and it's true, when the map is the selected tab the map loads fine.

Here is our markup:

```
<xe:djTabPane id="djTabPaneMap" title="Map">
            <xp:panel style="height:290px;width:860px" id="panel6">
                <xc:ccGoogleMaps map_height="290" map_width="860"
                    map_width_measurement="px" map_height_measurement="px"
                    map_zoom="5" map_type="ROADMAP" map_center_type="Address"
                    map_center_address="Broadstairs">
                </xc:ccGoogleMaps>
                </xp:panel>
            </xe:djTabPane>
```

It's really basic stuff I know, but we can't seem to get the initialise map function called from switching the tab.

Any ideas???

I am afraid that despite many attempts to call the build map function on tab change - using either the ID or CSS class name we are unable to draw our map fully.

When the map is outside the tabbed panel there is no issue.

Once I use Firebug to inspect the panel the map renders correctly

Many thanks!

Andrew

Comment: Have you considered to use XSP.onLoad(..) to add a listener to the tab click (or tab change) event?

Comment: did you try to initialize map in onClientLoad event inside CC?

Comment: I have tried using onLoad to add a listener with no success. I also tried a tab change event which also didn't work. If you throw a three tabbed pane up in an xpage with a google map on the third tab you will see the same issue - or at least I hope you do, or i'm doing something very wrong! I'm grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a Google map must be in an IFRAME. Or is it ?

Comment: I don't need to worry about an iFrame as the CC writes this out for me